# Can not retrieve values from PHP Session Variable Array

Tags: php, arrays, session

So basically I have a dynamic page that displays products that belong to the user and if any jobs are running on thier product it will display the status by the product.

The problem I have is that if I activated a job on a single product it would display that job on all the products on the page.

I am trying to figure out a solution for it and thought that the session variables I currently use to get the job name and product id I could instead make into an array and then only apply the job status on the relevant products. However I can not get it to work. THis is my current code.

PHP

```
foreach($_SESSION['vAppJobInfo'] as $jobInfo){

    if($jobInfo['id'] == $vApp->get('id') ){

        $curActiveJobName = $jobInfo['name'];
        $curActiveJobvAppId = $jobInfo['id'];

    }
}
```

PHP on processing page

```
$_SESSION['vAppJobInfo']['id'] = $_GET["id"];


if($_GET["action"]==="start"){

$job = new job();
$job->createStartVAppJob($clientId,$vCloudDirectorId,$vAppId);

$_SESSION['curMessage'] = $languageDB->berkGet("content_start_vApp_job_created");
$_SESSION['vAppJobInfo']['name'] = $languageDB->berkGet("content_start_vapp");
header('Location: /vAppManage.php?vdcId='.$vApp->get("orgVirtualDatacenterId"));
}
```

Anytime the user starts a job the process page is called.

I am sure my logic is just wrong or I am going about things the wrong way. any help is appreciated.

Comment: obvious question #1: are you calling `session_start()` EVERYWHERE you're using the session?

Comment: Yes,  I have other session variables I set on the processing page and use on the front end page and they work fine, none of them are arrays though just standard session variables.

Comment: php (mostly) couldn't care less what you put into the session. it's just an array like any other. the only thing that makes it special is the auto-save functionality, and even then it's just basically getting serialize()'d to a file. if your data can survive serialization, then it'll "work" in $_SESSION.

Comment: I feel like I am going about making the array in the wrong way.  I need an array that basically would have  id and name for each index of the array if that makes sense.  so like if you were on  the page  and you had ran two jobs and printed that array out it should have like   ID=1 Name = StartVm  and  ID = 2 and Name = StartVm

Comment: then `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what's in there, and check it before/after you try to set the values. maybe the session's working perfectly, but your languageDB calls are failing.

Comment: Basically everytime the process page is called a need another id and name added to the array on its own row. Do I have my stuff set up correctly to achieve this?